# Android DataBinding : View flickering

Tags: android, performance, android-databinding

I am using `GridView` with image items, loading image via A`ndroid DataBinding technology`. If add some new item to list and notify the adapter then the GridView gets flickering why its occur ? if i am not using  DataBinding technology then its work fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using data binding in a list, you should always call [executePendingBindings()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#executePendingBindings()) - this causes the binding to execute immediately, rather than wait for the next frame (which is what causes the flickering).

Comment: if you are looking for an example with gifs about executePendingBindings I added a reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996894/android-why-use-executependingbindings/68667411#68667411